# Android Memory Leaks Issue

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I was experiencing a memory leak problem with one of my apps, and after many hours, I instead decided to create a new project as a dumbed down version of the app:

- The app contains 2 activites
- The first page xml has 3 `ImageView`s with src and formatting. The code listens for clicks on one of those and opens a new activity (second activity).
- The second just has 2 `ImageView`s and 2 `EditText`s. The `.java` does nothing
- I only have 4 images in `drawable`
- It's a new project with only these two added activities and a new style (just made it full screen)

The problem:

- Clicking on the listend-to `ImageView` gives an OOM exception.
- the heap size is about 45 MB, 91% full

More Details:

- I tried Memory Analyzer. I only have 1 instance of my class. The problem suspects (1 & 2 which account > 75%) is `byte[]` loaded by `<system class loader>`
- I also found the Error 'A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released' in my Log, which makes no sense based on the above.

I've spent all day on this, and created countless new projects just to test it, and I'm still lost. I know most people can't provide an answer based on the given information, but **if you can tell me the next steps, or some things to try to figure out the problem, that counts as an answer too**.

Comment: Are you using an emulator or an attached device ?
because i had a similar problem with the emulators and when I changed to an external android device the problem solved and everything goes well .

Comment: emulator, but couldn't switching to a device just make the error go away because of a potentially larger heap size? So the problem would still exist on lower-end devices (which I don't have to test).

Did you test it on your phone or something closer to the minimum-supported you were looking for?

Comment: I tried my app on SonyErecson Xperia mini (st15i) 1GB CPU and 512MB ram , 3" screen 320 X 480 resolution , android version 4.0.4 ICS
it's an old phone first released on 2011 and my app have multiple threads with heavy calculation and it worked properly while on the emulator it always crashes with OutOfMemory error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your AppManifest.xml in your application tag this code:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

This will try to prevent your app from causing OutOfMemoryError.

**Documentation:** http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap

Although this is not a very recommended solution, it should still work...

You can also try to decrease your images' resolution if they are so large.

If problem still persists, I highly recommend to check this link: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions? Or maybe even guesses about where the leak could have come from?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use BitmapFactory, check my updated answer.

Comment: This might be useful, but why would my images take up so much space, considering their total size is less than 0.5 MB? I don't have any code written right now, so there's no way they are loaded multiple times.. or is that possible? Before I invest time in trying your solution, I'd like to know why it's happening in the first place if that's possible. Could you try guessing, please?

Comment: How is your app lifecycle? Do you open a certain activity that contains images, then open another activity that also contains other images, then return back to the first activity that had images? Does your app act something like that? Also if their total size is 0.5, that should be good. You should also take use of onPause() or onStop() methods to free some memory or something. If you can post some code please, it will be easier to help. Also be aware that the emulator is not as fast as a real android device, so that might be the problem. Try to test it on a real android device better.

Comment: FOR FUTURE READERS:

add the image under drawbale-nodpi then manipulate the bitmaps. Marked as correct since it led me to the answer I wanted. Thanks